# Are there any US Census columns that can give me information about rents with respect to the size of housing units? (bedroom, sf, etc)

Tags: us-census, real-estate

The US Census department provides a fair amount of data on rents within areas. Median Gross Rent, Average Gross Rent, you've got the normally bands of rents ($800-$999, $1000-$1249, etc). But these rent numbers could be for 1BR apartments or massive homes. Are there any columns that could shed some light on rents with respect to the size of housing units? I don't think the census department collects square footage of homes, but maybe bedrooms?

Comment: hi, i believe they do collect all of that info.  perhaps start here?  http://www.asdfree.com/search/label/american%20housing%20survey%20%28ahs%29

Comment: This information is absolutely collected in the survey. I can't find a place where the data in the particular cross section you are asking about is published, though. The questionnaire is publicly available here: https://www2.census.gov/programs-surveys/ahs/2015/AHS%202015%20Items%20Booklet.pdf

Answer (score 1):

You want table [B25068 'Bedrooms by gross rent'](https://factfinder.census.gov/bkmk/table/1.0/en/ACS/15_5YR/B25068/1600000US3651000) from the American Community Survey 5 year estimates for the most recent years (as of April 2017, that would be 2011-2015).

The ACS data has some pitfalls - pay attention to the margin of error because it'll show values for small geographies but they'll have margins that make them useless. If that comes as news to you then Google for [a tutorial](https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/acs/guidance/training-presentations/acs-moe.html) or post another question for more details.

For use in news reporting I was able to get to zip code or CDP subdivision level with reasonable margins of error. YMMV depending on use case. HTH!

Comment: ACS Data User community (https://acsdatacommunity.prb.org/) specializes in fine points about ACS.